# How do you summon an entity with several tags?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Like the title says, I want to summon a villager with several tags from the start. This is because I have several villagers with the tag `extra`, so I can't add tag `CorpFred` to a villager with the tag `extra` because then all villagers with that tag will also have `CorpFred`. So, how would you summon a villager with several tags? (Note this is for version 1.9.4)

`/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Offers:{},Tags:["extra"],CustomName:"Corporal Frederickson",NoAI:1b}`

If you could add the tag `CorpFred` to this `/summon` command, I would be highly grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add more than one list-style property to an item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/385588/how-can-i-add-more-than-one-list-style-property-to-an-item)

Comment: @pppery I presume the same technique is used to solve the problem both here and in the suggested duplicate, but both seem like distinct enough questions for them to remain open.

Comment: @Joachim I agree. MSE says that if understanding how these questions are related requires anything more than basic changes, they are not duplicates, merely related.

Comment: I consider that question in its entirety to be "Basic Changes", so can't really engage with ExpertCoder14's arguments other than to say all of my [tag:minecraft-commands] duplicate close votes assume a certain level of familiarity with command syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tags` is just a list, `[]`, of strings, `""`. To add multiple elements to a list, separate them with commas:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {Offers:{},Tags:["extra","CorpFred"],CustomName:"Corporal Frederickson",NoAI:1b}
```

Comment: oh well rip me. I figured a way around it last night, I added the `CorpFred` tag to the NPC, then I would do `/scoreboard players tag @e[type=Villager,tag=CorpFred] add extra` but I will use yours as it is much quicker. Thank you!