# How do I add multiple effects to my custom potion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make custom potions for my Minecraft 1.17 server. The current command that I have is as follows:

```
give @p minecraft:potion{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:1, Amplifier:0, Duration:600}], CustomPotionColor:65280, display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Super Awesome Potion\"}"}}
```

The item given by this command is a potion named "Super Awesome Potion" and has the Speed status effect on it.

But I don't know how I can put multiple effects on this potion. Is it possible?

Comment: "[...] So i wanted to ask how to make multi effect potions [...]" Sounds like a question to me. I think him showing how to do a named one is just to show effort.

Comment: @pppery Are you sure? The question was just worded in a weird way. It's still a question.

Comment: It seemed to me like a question and answer combined into one post. But this is irrelevant, since, even after applying an edit that IMO deviates from the original intent of the post, you're left with a duplicate of [How would I have more than one enchantment at level 1000 in Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/385588/185203), so the question should still be closed.

Comment: @pppery To close as a duplicate of that question, that question must be clarified how the concept extends to other situations. My edit does not change the intent of the post, it was just worded in a way that sounds like a question and an answer in one. It's not.

Comment: @pppery There you go, that question you linked is now a canonical with the same fundamental concept. We can now close this one correctly.